# Change label text depending on what Table View Cell was pressed (Storyboard)

Tags: iphone, xcode, storyboard

I have some cells in a table view that when pressed leads to a view controller that has a label that I want to change.

Example: I have cells representing the biggest citys in America, I press Los Angeles and I get sent to the view controller with the label that changes to a number representing LA. If I go back and press New York the label now displays a number representing New York.

I would guess I give the label and cells identifiers and make some kind of if/else if.

Something like this:

"if 'newyorkcell' isPressed setText 'numbercell' = "12345";"

But with real code.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you'll have to make a public outlet of your label in your view controllers header file:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *yourLabel;

@end
```

Then you can set that labels text via didSelectRow, for this you have to give your detail view controller a storyboard id (in the storyboard) to be able to access it here in code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ViewController *detailViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VC"];

    detailViewController.yourLabel.text = [self.yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [self.navigationController presentViewController:detailViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Instead of using if/elses you could use an array or something where you have all your data in and access it using its index.

Comment: This isn't going to work. The `yourLabel` outlet isn't set yet in `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: Thx, you're right, I forgot about that.. Just modified the answer and put everything in didSelectRow, where it should be working.